# Multiple hasProperty constraints for Hamcrest matcher

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I tried the following code, for matching a single ComplexObject in a List

```
assertThat(complexObjectList, Matchers.<ComplexObject>hasItems(
    hasProperty("lang", equalTo(lang)), 
    hasProperty("name", equalTo(name)),
    hasProperty("desc", equalTo(desc)));
```

I want to have a filter of

`match(lang) && match(name) && match(desc)`

but with the above code, i get

`match(lang) || match(name) || match(desc)`

How can I verify those three different `hasProperty` matchers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `allOf` matcher.

```
assertThat(complexObjectList,
  Matchers.<ComplexObject>hasItem(allOf(
    hasProperty("lang", equalTo(lang)),
    hasProperty("name", equalTo(name)),
    hasProperty("desc", equalTo(desc))));
```